# Is there any reason to train above Piloting 1?

Tags: dust-514

The piloting skill says that it unlocks other skills for flying, but the only thing right now is drop-ships, which only take Piloting 1. Is there any reason at all to train above 1 in piloting?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a reason currently, due to the only thing available being drop-ships.

As CCP does updates for the game during the open beta (and continuing after release) there may be skills or ships that require or benefit from a higher piloting skill.

Answer (score 0):

As of patch 1.7 this skill is no longer in the game.  This is now handled under the skill **Vehicle Command**.

The **Vehicle Command** skill provides no bonus of its own but it is required to unlock subsequent vehicle skills.  They are (and require):

- **LAV Operation** (**Vehicle Command**-Level 1)
- **Dropship Operation** (**Vehicle Command**-Level 3)
- **HAV Operation** (**Vehicle Command**-Level-5)

Both LAV (Light Attack Vehicle) and HAV (Light Attack Vehicle) skills only unlock the ability to operate those vehicles.

The **Dropship Operation** skill unlocks the ability to operate standard dropships.  Raising this to Level 3 unlocks the Assault Dropships skill.

The **Assault Dropships** skill unlocks Assault Dropships of all races.  It also increased small turret damage by 2% per level trained. Once this is trained to Level 1 you unlock the following skills:

- **Caldari Assault Dropship**

Each level grants a 10% bonus to missile turret rate of fire and 5% bonus to the amount of maximum ammo for missile turrets to Caldari Assault Dropships.

- **Gallente Assault Dropship**

Each level grants a 10% bonus to hybrid turret rate of fire and 5% bonus to the amount of maximum ammo for hybrid turrets to Gallente Assault Dropships.